# What a word for "navigate" that's more commonly associated with land?

Tags: single-word-requests

[According to Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/navigate) it means *guide along route, often over water*. Are there other similar words but that are more commonly associated with land/terrain? Example:

> I found it difficult to [...] in that mountain. There were too many trees.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Navigate" would often be used in this sense... you could also use **"negotiate"** - if there were a lot of obstructions on your path. (You wouldn't use "in", with it.)

Answer (score 3):

You could indeed use *navigate*, alternatively, you could use *travel*:

> I found it difficult to travel in that mountain. There were too many trees.

However, I would suggest changing the sentence around instead. Something like:

> Walking on that mountain was hard.
>
> Navigating the mountain was hard.

Or even

> [The going was hard](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hard+going) on that mountain.

Answer (score 2):

'To traverse' is another alternative. Best fits the need here I guess, as evidenced by example sentences used to illustrate the meaning of traverse... (Eg: He traversed the forest wearily.)

Answer (score 1):

I found it difficult to navigate that mountain.  (no 'in')

I found it difficult to climb that mountain.  ('climb' being the most typical very associated with mountains)

I found it difficult to ascend that mountain.

It's true that 'negotiate' could also work, as the previous answer states.

Answer (score 0):

There is a niche sport called "[orienteering](http://www.us.orienteering.org/new-o/what-orienteering)" where:

> orienteers use an accurate, detailed map and a compass to find points in the landscape. It can be enjoyed as a walk in the woods or as a competitive sport.

As such, the verb "[to orienteer](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/orienteer?s=t)" is something you hear people use when talking about finding their way in, for instance, a dense wood.

To speak to your example, you would say,

> I found it difficult to *orienteer* on that mountain. There were too many trees.

Unlike the verb "to orient" which takes a reflexive pronoun in that case, you would not follow the same construct with "to orienteer".

Comment: +1 Not sure why this has been voted down???? *orientate* according to [definition No.2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orientate) Seems to be what the OP is asking for?

Comment: I found it difficult to orientate myself on that mountain. There were too many trees.

Comment: I like orientate real well. It is a BrE spelling though, right?

Comment: The OP did not specify.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a terrestrial equivalent for "navigate". But since what you mean is that you found it difficult to find the way in that mountain, why don't you just say exactly that?

Answer (score 0):

*Orientate* according to [definition No.2](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orientate)

> I found it difficult to orientate myself on that mountain. There were too many trees.

Or *map-read* could also be used [*map-read*](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/map+reading):-

The determination of position by identification of landmarks with their representations on a map or chart.

> I found it difficult to map-read on that mountain. There were too many trees